# Any existing library to mock just some mutations/queries?

Tags: mocking, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

My application is currently under development and fully mocked up. I would like to step by step release some GraphQL queries and mutations as soon as they are linked to the API and working.

Do you know a library that already implements kind of structure/patterns to do that?

Otherwise I was thinking about setting a middleware before sending the request and depending on the query/mutation name, I would either use the production URL or use the mocked data.

Thank you,

Comment: `apollo-server` [already supports partial mocking](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/mocking#customizing-mocks). How is your server being "fully mocked" right now? By setting `mocks` to true?

Comment: Hi @DanielRearden, I'm not using apollo-server (my API is not in JS), I'm currently using https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-faker but it seems there is no way to easily switch ON/OFF requests mocks (I mean, a specific query/mutation for example)